# Retract of $F_2$ onto $[F_2,F_2]$

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

I'm trying to show that the commutator subgroup  $[F_2,F_2]$ is not a retract of $F_2$. I was trying to do the proof by contradiction so I assume there is a retract $f: F_2 \to [F_2,F_2]$, then I know this is surjective and then I tried to apply abelianization to get the map $f^{ab}: \mathbb{Z}^2 \to {1}$ but this doesn't give me any contradictions since this map is surjective. Then I was thinking to apply the universal property of quotient groups somehow because I know $F_2/ [F_2,F_2] = \mathbb{Z}^2$ and that is a surjective map but I can't find anything that gives me a contradiction. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

Abelianization does give you a contradiction; $[F_2, F_2]$ is a free group on countably many generators, so its abelianization is the free abelian group on countably many generators, and $f^{ab}$ can't be surjective.

Comment: why can't $f^{ab}$ be surjective isn't the abelianization of $[F_2,F_2]$ the trivial group?

Comment: @Sasha: no. As I just said, the abelianization of $[F_2, F_2]$ is the free abelian group on countably many generators. You're getting confused because the map induced by the inclusion $[F_2, F_2] \to F_2$ on abelianizations is trivial, but that doesn't imply that the abelianization is itself trivial. Concretely, the abelianization of $[F_2, F_2]$ is the quotient by its commutator subgroup $[[F_2, F_2], [F_2, F_2]]$, *not* by the commutator subgroup of $F_2$.

Comment: oh I see.. and $[F_2,F_2]$ is not finetely generated because $F_2$ is infinite.

Comment: @Sasha: I'm not sure what argument you have in mind. $[F_2, F_2]$ is not finitely generated because e.g. you can write down the covering space of the wedge of two circles it corresponds to and that covering is an infinite covering (it's the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$, more or less).

Comment: is there a relationship between the degree of the covering map and the subgroup of $\Pi_1(X)$ you choose to quotient the universal cover by?

Comment: @Sasha: the degree of the covering map is the index of the subgroup. But sorry, I didn't finish the argument: it's not enough to observe that the covering is infinite. We also need to observe that the covering has a spanning tree which omits countably many edges, so it's homotopy equivalent to a wedge of countably many circles.

Comment: thank you! This all makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

We can make the previous argument more precise. The group $[F_2,F_2]$ is a free group. It is freely generated by elements of the form $a^n b^m [a,b]b^{-m}a^{-n}$, for $n, m\in \bf Z$, as it is the fundmantal group of the Cayley graph of $\bf Z^2$ viewed as a quotient $F_2/[F_2,F_2]$, so it is not finitely generated.

Comment: but isn't $F^2/[F_2,F_2] = \mathbb{Z^2}$ so it is finetly generated? I'm confused on how that gives me a contradiction.

Comment: Yu are unterested by the derived group $[F_2, F_2]$ which is not.